# GWT RPC AsynCallback skips onSucces and onFail methods

Tags: java, gwt, asynchronous, callback, rpc

I've try to code a GWT application and I need to use RPC to get results from server side. I followed the GWT RPC tutorial and end up with some goods. But when I debug my program, I saw that my program skips onFailure and onSuccess methods, so that I got nullpointerexception.
Here is necessary parts of my implementation.

```
IRecordServiceAsync recordSvc = GWT.create(IRecordService.class);
private class RecordCallBack implements AsyncCallback<Records> {
    public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public void onSuccess(Records result) {
        records = result.getRecords();
    }

}
public void onModuleLoad() {
setFileGridData(getRecords());
.
.
.
}
public HashMap getRecords() {
    recordSvc.getRecords(recordclass, new RecordCallBack());
    return this.records;
}
```

As I said my program skpis the onFailure and onSuccess parts, because of that my records value becomes null.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Hint: asynchronous == non-blocking.

Comment: possible duplicate of [gwt return value when asynchronous callback end](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15719866/gwt-return-value-when-asynchronous-callback-end)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to think *asynchronously*. The method `getRecords()`, first does an *async* call to your service, and then immediately return the `records` field, that will always be null (assuming never modified so far).

You have to *wait* the respose to return (handled by `onSuccess`/`onFailure`). And, in general, never use getters that rely on async calls, but design your app to `wait` for responses/events.

In your case, simply put the async call into the `onModuleLoad()` and only inside `onSuccess()`, use the `setFileGridData(result.getRecords())`, avoiding the getter at all.

Comment: I've added this line inside 'recordSvc.getRecords(recordclass, this);' the onModuleLoad
and I've added setFileGridData(getRecords()); to the onSuccess, also I've called onSuccess(recordclass); this in filegrid processes.
I've understood what you tried to say but I guess I couldn't implement my code. This still gives null value.

Comment: You don't have to call `onSuccess()`. It [gets called for you](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/AsyncCallback.html), when the response will come back from the server.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating new RecordCallBack.So onFailure and onSuccess will be called on the new instance.Instead of doing that, you could try following

```
public void getRecords() {
    recordSvc.getRecords(recordclass, this);
}
```

Comment: I've tried this but I still got null value for recordclass variable

Comment: I've just corrected the part you've said but nothing has changed. Which part do u need? I would edit it.

Answer (score 1):

After all the explanations

your code should like

```
onModuleLoad(){
  recordSvc.getRecords(new RecordCallBack<Records>(){


 public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public void onSuccess(Records result) {
        records = result.getRecords();
        setFileGridData(records);
    }

});

}
```